# How to manipulate html elements in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

It is necessary to delete a class from another element when clicking on one element in the virtual DOM.

In jQuery, this is quite simple:

```
$(1.element).click(function() {
  $(2.element).removeClass(className);
}
```

How to achieve the same in Vue???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/515644/) with the demo to remove a class binding.

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="button" v-on:click="isActive = false" value="button"/>
  <input :class="{ active: isActive }"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      isActive: true
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. You should not be touching the DOM directly like `.removeClass`. This is the way you'd do it in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the vm-on to get the event object in the template, and them with some data bind (v-bind) change the value class (classToChange) of your template. Something like this.

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: function () {
    return classToChange = 'old-class'
  }
  methods: {
    click: function (ev) {
      this.classToChange = 'new-class'
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on